# What is "Hand Held Laser Compatible" (HHLC) protocol?

Tags: barcode

What exactly is being output by a bar code scanner if it is an HHLC device. So far, I've been able to gather that it is an undecoded signal. How is it different from the signal that is being output by scanning wand/pen? There a few mentions in manuals of scanners which can emulate those two, stating that they are different from each other but not how.

Comment: Why the downvote? Does "This question [...] not show any research effort; [...] is [it] unclear or not useful"?

Answer (score 0):

HHLC aka "Laser emulation" is a low level protocol for interfacing to smart external decoders for a variety of bar-code formats.

This is usually employed by CCD scanners and strips the intelligence of a complex label to just the binary bar code sequence to a serial port with handshaking rather than a higher level of communication.

A Wand scanner has variable sweep rates while a wand is hand actuated sweep.  All 3 devices types can use the same protocol with a smart  external decoder using the HHLC or Laser emulation protocol.

Other optional interfaces exclusive from this are ASCII over RS-232, TTL, keyboard wedge, EBCDIC, etc.

Comment: Ok, so in essence, it's binary data maybe with some _start_ and _stop_ signals while wand emulation outputs an analog signal which is changing its voltage level depending on the light that gets reflected from the black and white portions of the code. Is that about right?